# Sending Nested Query with Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel

I'm sending a series of loops from controller to viewe but I have to return a loop in it.

i want to do something like code

```
$sor1 = mysql_query("select * from dersler");

while(mysql_fetch_object($sor1)) {
    $dersid = $sor1->id;
    $sor = mysql_query("select * from gecilendersler where dersid='$dersid'");

    while(mysql_fetch_object($sor)) {
        echo $sor->dersadi;
    }
}


$uyeid  =Auth::user()->id;
$dersler = DB::table('dersler')->where('uyeid', $uyeid)->get(); 

foreach($dersler as $ders) {
    $dersid=$ders->id;
}

$saatler = DB::table('saatler')->where('dersid', $dersid)->get();

return view('sayfalar.saatler')
    ->with([
        'dersler' => $dersler,
        'saatler' => $saatler
    ]);
```

I did it this way, but the last record remains in the last line in other records

Comment: i dont make I'm stuck

Comment: I suggest visiting [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there.